# ASP.NET WebService - Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have an ASP.NET webservice that is making use of Entity Framework 4.0.

When I run one of the methods on the WebService locally, it is throwing the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: To be XML
>   serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an
>   implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their
>   inheritance hierarchy.
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[testGoogleEarth.Model.Marker,
>   testGoogleEarth, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] does not implement Add(System.Object).    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetEnumeratorElementType(Type type,
>   TypeFlags& flags)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.ImportTypeDesc(Type type,
>   MemberInfo memberInfo, Boolean directReference)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo
>   source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.CreateUnknownTypeException(Type
>   type)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String
>   name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String
>   n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write7_JsonResult(String
>   n, String ns, JsonResult o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write9_JsonResult(Object
>   o)    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter
>   xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String
>   encodingStyle, String id)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String
>   encodingStyle, String id)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter
>   textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse
>   response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[]
>   returnValues)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()

I am running this sample on a Windows Server 2008. .NET 4.0 installed.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please, while asking a question you no need to give a page of Exception, instead post your code first and give the main sentense in your exception. So, that we can help you.

Comment: this is the entire exception I got! Im using ASP.NET web service with Ef 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with the XMLSerializer you are using to serialize the WCF request across the wire. Any IEnumerable class in your object graph should have a public add method. See some details here
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YouMustImplementTheAddSystemObjectMethodOnMyClassBecauseItInheritsFromIEnumerable.aspx

Comment: Its an ASP.NET Web Service not WCF using EF 4.0

Comment: Sorry my bad, but the issue is related to serializer and not the WCF service\asmx service. Did you check the object graph?

Comment: How to check the object graph? No idea actually. Thanks

Comment: For objects that you are sending over wire, check them and their child object and make sure if any of these objects have an IEnumerable define, they should also have Add method